# How to uses pipes?

Tags: r, pipe

I'm trying to use pipes but I think something is wrong with my syntaxis.
When I write:

```
mean(b_2021_01$Day.of.week, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Everything is ok, but when I write...

```
b_2021_01 %>% mean(Day.of.week, na.rm=T)
```

An error message appears "Warning message:
In mean.default(., Day.of.week, na.rm = T) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

The "Day.of.week" variable is an int, I don't understand why it says that my argument is not numeric.

Comment: As explained by @akrun already, what you can do is : `mtcars$mpg %>% mean(na.rm=TRUE)` is the same as `mtcars %>% mutate(mean_mpg = mean(mpg, na.rm=T))`

Comment: @TarJae It really isn’t the same. One returns a vector, the other a data.frame.

Comment: Oh ok. Many thanks. You are completely right. I had in mind the position of mpg. in the first example on the left side, in the second on the right side!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pull` to extract the column and then use `mean`

```
library(magrittr)
b_2021_01 %>%
    pull(Day.of.week) %>%
    mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or wrap with `{}`

```
b_2021_01 %>% 
    {mean(.$Day.of.week, na.rm=TRUE)}
```

---

Or use exposition operator (`%$%`)

```
b_2021_01 %$%
   mean(Day.of.week, na.rm = TRUE)
```

-testing

```
> mtcars %$%
    mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 20.09062
```

---

The reason for the error is the first argument `x` should be a vector, but on the rhs of `%>%`, it is taken as the whole data.frame as input

```
> mtcars %>% mean(.$mpg, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(., .$mpg, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

> mean(mtcars, mtcars$mpg )
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(mtcars, mtcars$mpg) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```